# Jquery re-binding every element I unbinded

Tags: jquery, click, unbind

Im trying to unbind a click call on element and than unbind the unbind.
I know i can use a handler to handle each and each click, but im using unbind on too many element by using for example:

```
$(".classname").unbind('click');
```

and so i can allow to myself to just write it 1 by one, any other esthetic way and way more efficient than writing it 1 by 1 ?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

detailed example : 
i got many buttons which all have same css class,
when i press 1 specific button i need all of the rest to be unbinded from clicking them.
after the button i pressed finishes his purpese i need to re-bind all the click events again.
Thats is what i ment when i said unbind the unbind.

Comment: what is  unbind the unbind.

Comment: Can you post more detail? How are your handlers bound in the first place? Can we see some source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unbind your buttons to avoid multi-calling of the function, why didn't you define a global boolean variable like `inProcess`.
You check if it was `true` or `false` in the beginning of your function and it's done!

Like this :

```
var inProcess = false;
function myFunction() {
    if (!inProcess) {
        inProcess = true;
        // some logic code here
        inProcess = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

It's almost the same process, but, it's lighter for your browser than "bind"/"unbind" multiple time.

Comment: seems legit as they say

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want a handful of the elements to have click events and not the rest. To achieve this just give the elements an arbitrary class name so you can use this as a jQuery selector.

```
<p class="classname">Some element</p>
<p class="classname">Some element</p>
<p class="classname">Some element</p>
<p class="classname arbitraryclassname">Some element</p>
<p class="classname arbitraryclassname">Some element</p>
<p class="classname arbitraryclassname">Some element</p>
```

Then in Jquery use

```
$(".arbitraryclassname").bind('click', function() { 
     // Some logic
});
```